# append values from list in different set lists

Tags: python

So I have a shortlist that has different values. And I want to split that list based on the condition of value and append it to a different list. Better yet if I can show you example

```
my_list = [211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314]
```

and I want to iterate from 211-230, and from 253-272 and from 295-314 and append it to a new list to do a `for loop` from it. I have an excel that I read.

```
location_of_rows = [10, 12]
    for j in range(location_of_rows[0], location_of_rows[1]):
            for i in my_List:
                if i is range(211,230,1):
                    val1 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
                elif i is range(253,272,1):
                    val2 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
                else i is range(295,314,1):
                    val3 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
             if val1 and val2 and val3 != '':
                 avg(val1+val2+val3)
        else: 
            pass
```

I hope it's clear what I am trying to do. If not ill put a simple excel table with it :)

Comment: You should use `in` instead of `is`, when you're doing membership test

Comment: can you format your code in proper way with indents ?

Comment: Maybe to clarify: your `my_list` represents indices? then you extract values from an excel sheet based on these indices and some conditions? what does `avg` do?

Comment: I am missing the question in your question. You posted some code but didn't tell us what is not working

Comment: I thought I made it clear that I wrote this and its not working :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
location_of_rows = [10, 12]
    for j in range(location_of_rows[0], location_of_rows[1]+1):
        for i in my_List:
            if i in range(211,231,1):
                val1 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
            elif i in range(253,273,1):
                val2 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
            else i in range(295,315,1):
                val3 = ws_exp.cell_value(i,j)
        if val1 != '' and val2 != '' and val3 != '':
            avg(val1+val2+val3)
```

Note that you were using `is` instead of `in` as written in a comment.

Note that the second argument of the [range function](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=range+python&t=h_&ia=web) is not included.

And note that  this is correct: `val1 != '' and val2 != '' and val3 != ''`, not this: `val1 and val2 and val3 != ''`.

Comment: invalid syntax at else

Answer (score 0):

Appending it to three different list with conditons:

```
l_211_230 = []
l_253_272 = []
l_294_314 = []

for i in my_list:
    if(i >=211) and (i<= 230):
        l_211_230.append(i)
    elif(i >=253) and (i<= 272):
        l_253_272.append(i)
    elif(i >=294) and (i<= 314):
        l_294_314.append(i)
```